# Load a Symfony sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice select with a limited set of results

Tags: forms, doctrine, symfony1

I am developing a form in a Symfony application where a user must indicate a country, a region and an optional island using HTML `select` elements.

I have three models: Country, Region and Island; and Symfony has auto-generated three widgets in the form using the `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice` widget:

```
...
'country_id' => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('Country'), 'add_empty' => false)),
'region_id'  => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('Region'), 'add_empty' => false)),
'island_id'  => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('Island'), 'add_empty' => true)),
...
```

Since the country list is large, and so the region list, I've been thinking on filtering the options available in `Region` and `Island` according to the value selected in Country.

Doing this after the HTML document is ready is easy with jQuery's `change` method and a simple AJAX request. But I wonder if there's a way of doing this directly from Symfony, perhaps in form configuration, to have a default combined selection.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: So, do want it load via ajax or show/hide by javascript?

Comment: Checkout [sfDependentSelectPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDependentSelectPlugin)

Comment: I checked it out and didn't like. For my specific requirements it's too complex. I'll post what I ended up doing

Comment: Would be great to see the rest of your code related to updating the select fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with [sfDependentSelectPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDependentSelectPlugin), I ended up assigning custom queries to initialize the HTML select elements:

```
$countryId = $this->getObject()->getCountry()->getTable()->getDefaultCountryId();
$regionId = $this->getObject()->getRegion()->getTable()->getDefaultRegionId($countryId);
$islandId = $this->getObject()->getIsland()->getTable()->getDefaultIslandId($regionId);

$this->widgetSchema->setDefault('country_id', $countryId);

$this->setWidget('region_id', new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array(
    'model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('Region'),
    'query' => $this->getObject()->getRegion()->getTable()->getRegionsQuery($countryId),
    'default' => $regionId,
)));

$this->setWidget('island_id', new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array(
    'model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('Island'),
    'query' => $this->getObject()->getIsland()->getTable()->getIslandsQuery($regionId),
    'add_empty' => '---',
    'default' => $islandId,
)));
```

And then updating the options available with AJAX requests using jQuery. The good thing is that the actions that handle the AJAX requests use the same query methods above to return a new set of results.